# Not able to pass values b/w components using @Input

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I want to pass `FailedProductId` from Component1 to Component2 using `@Input` but it is not working for me. See my code below

```
export class Component1 implements OnInit {

public FailedProductId="produt";
constructor(private employeeService: ProductService) {}
}
}
```

`.html` file of Component1

```
<div> 
 <app-device-list [parentData]="FailedProductId"></app-device-list>

  <table>
    <th>Id</th><th>Active</th><th>Name</th><th>Platform</th><th>ManagedBy</th>

    <th> Compliant</th> <th>InProgress</th><th>Failed</th>

    <tr *ngFor="let lst of products.Products; let i = index" border="1">
      <td>{{lst.GroupName}}</td>
      <td (click)="devicesClicked()">{{lst.Compliant}}</td>
      <td>{{lst.InProgress}}</td>
      <td> <a routerLink="/devicelist/{{lst.ID.Value}}">{{lst.Failed}}</a> </td>
    </tr>

  </table>   
</div>
```

`Component2.ts` file code

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-device-list',
  template: ' <h2>{{"Hello "+ parentData}}</h2> '
})

export class Component2 implements OnInit {

  @Input() public parentData;

  }
```

This line  `'<h2>{{"Hello "+ parentData}}</h2>'` giving output `Hello undefined`.

Comment: What's `NgModule` doing btwn `@Component` and `Component`?

Comment: @Paritosh - I have commented that code, still not working.

Comment: There seems to be no problem with your code unless you have a typo in your original code.Your code should work to show "Hello produt" as the output.

Comment: @KeshavPradeepRamanath - Please check my updated code of Component1's html file

Comment: All other code which is added is not relevant to the output which you require.The passing of data from Parent to Child is already happening in 2nd line of Parent Component's html. Other lines are purely business logic and should not have a bearing on the output i think

Comment: @KeshavPradeepRamanath - When leaving comp2 and coming back to comp1(by modifying url and hitting enter) comp2 `ngOnInit()` hitting and showing correct value here `console.log("parentdata "+this.parentData);` but when going comp1 to comp2, `this.parentData` value showing undefined(while debugging).

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your second component like this:
And also check if that data is set in first component.

```js
@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  selector: 'app-device-list',
  template: ' <h2>{{"Hello "+ parentData}}</h2> '
})

export class Component2 implements OnInit {

  @Input() public parentData;

  }
```

Comment: Your code not working. I am setting data  at time of declaring variable.

Comment: How do you set your FailedProductId, and can you verify it has been loaded into this variable? Can you show me code?

Comment: Try like this: <h2>Hello {{parentData}}</h2>, interpolation works only for variables, not text etc etc...